# How can I add spacebar on Header Nav Bar

Tags: html, css

So I made a navigation bar and a section lists and I successfully done it but the only problem is that the lists are not spaced. How do I fix this?

[How the Page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExSei.jpg)

```css
header {
  width:    100%;
  height:    80px;
  position:   fixed;
  top:    0;
  left:    0;
  background:   white;
  box-shadow:   0 32px 55px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index:    999;
}

header nav {
  float:    none;
  margin:    30px;
}

header nav ul li {
  display:    inline-block;
}

header nav ul li a {
  font-size:   16px;
}
```

```html
 <header>
  
  <nav id="nav-main">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#elektro_One">Elektro One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#über_uns">Über uns</a></li>
    <li><a href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#impressum">Impressum</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>

 </header>
```

Comment: wow on that indenting....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display evenly across the navbar and be responsive with screen then try using:

```
<ul id="even-space">
    <li>..</li>
    ..
</ul>
```

and css

```
#even-space {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add margin for `li` tags like following:

```css
header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: white;
 box-shadow: 0 32px 55px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 z-index: 999;
}

header nav {
 float: none;
 margin: 30px;
}

header nav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 16px;
}

header nav ul li a {
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
 <header>
  
  <nav id="nav-main">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#elektro_One">Elektro One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#über_uns">Über uns</a></li>
    <li><a href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#impressum">Impressum</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>

 </header>
```

Comment: Thank you so much lmao!

Answer (score 0):

Add "padding-left" and "padding-right" to the anchor tag CSS under "#nav-main" id. Please update below anchor CSS :

```
header nav ul li a  {
    font-size:16px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right:30px; }
```